# Is it correct to test assertions on a Uni running subscription on another thread in Mutiny?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mutiny

I am using Mutiny outside of Quarkus in a personal project.

I was writing some test cases on some `Uni`s and begin to notice that some assertions that should be passing, weren't reproducing the expected behavior.

A silly example:

```java
@Test
void test_retrieving_value_async() {
    Uni<String> uni = Uni.createFrom().item("Hello");
    var pool = ForkJoinPool.commonPool();
    var test = uni
            .runSubscriptionOn(pool)    
            .subscribe().withSubscriber(UniAssertSubscriber.create());
    test.assertCompleted().assertItem("Hello");
}
```

logs:

```
Expected a completion event, but didn't received it.
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected a completion event, but didn't received it.
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.helpers.test.AssertionHelper.fail(AssertionHelper.java:146)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.helpers.test.AssertionHelper.shouldHaveCompleted(AssertionHelper.java:24)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.helpers.test.UniAssertSubscriber.assertCompleted(UniAssertSubscriber.java:315)
...
```

The thing is that if I just comment out the `.runSubscriptionOn(pool)` line, the test pass as expected.

I am wondering if the best approach to test `Uni`s in Mutiny is to leave that asynchronous behavior out of the test cases.

Answer (score 0):

`assertCompleted` checks that the `Uni` has already been completed. In your case, you need `awaitCompletion`, which will await for the completion event or fails after a timeout.

BTW, `awaitCompletion` will pass even if the completion event has already been received.

Comment: I was able to achieve it with `awaitItem().assertItem("expected")`, method `awaitCompletion` is not defined for `UniAssertSubscriber<T>`.

Comment: ah yes sorry, `awaitItem()` / `awaitFailure()` are equivalent to `awaitCompletion()`